# Open Pikaday in a AngulasJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pikaday

It's being difficult to display the Pikaday in a AngularJS directive. For exemple:

**index.html:**

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

**controller.js**

```
MyApp.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: ".../my-directive.html",
    };
});
```

**my-directive.html:**

```
<input  id="view_service" type="text" readonly>
<div id="view_service_cont"></div>
```

**Pikaday config:**

```
const view_datepiker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('view_service'),
    container: document.getElementById('view_service_cont'),
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: new Date(2017, 0, 1), //Será necessário automatizar a data do calendário
    maxDate: new Date(2019, 12, 31),
    yearRange: [2017,2019],
    onSelect: function() {
        $scope.reset_pax();
        $scope.$digest();
        $scope.sale_form.date_selected = view_datepiker.getDate();
        //$('#datepicker').css('border-color','#78FA89');
        //$('#pax_num_container').css('border-color','#cccccc');
    },
    i18n: {
                previousMonth : 'Último mês',
                nextMonth     : 'Próximo mês',
                months        : ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
                weekdays      : ['Domingo','Segunda-Feira','Terça-Feira','Quarta-Feira','Quinta-Feira','Sexta-Feira','Sábado'],
                weekdaysShort : ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab']
            },
    disableDayFn: function(theDate) {
        theDate = theDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        if ($scope.current_service.availabilities.hasOwnProperty(theDate)) {
            return 0;
        }else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

When I tested the **input** directly in the **index.html**, it worked fine. But now I have created this directive to make the things simpler and when I click in the  field the datepiker does not show up.

Does anybody know how to show the Pikaday in a AngularJS directive?

Comment: Where is your config set? If you are using a directive you can try to put it in link. BTW if you put a jsfiddle or something maybe I can be more helpful, e.g what is $scope.current_service?

Comment: I've added this code: 
```console.log($('#view_service')[0]);```

When the element ```<input  id="view_service" type="text" readonly>``` is in the index.html the console log returns the text: ```<input  id="view_service" type="text" readonly>```

When the same element is in a angularJS directive it return ```undefined```

I think the problem is there... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**Investigation:** I've added this code:

```
console.log($('#view_service')[0]);
```

When the element `<input id="view_service" type="text" readonly>` is in the index.html the console log returns the following text: `<input id="view_service" type="text" readonly>`

When the same element is in a angularJS directive it returns: `undefined`

**My Suggestion** Since the page takes some time to load, the Pikaday configuration loads before the directive, so the element was not loaded on the DOM.

**Solution:** I put the Pikaday configuration after the code responsible to inform when the page is loaded and it worked fine.

I hope it can help people with the same issue!